# Local function updating two vars of enclosing method

Tags: function, scala, code-generation, var

Posting from the bus so I'll keep it short.

If a local function needs to access and update a local var of the enclosing method, the compiler has to translate the latter into an object, so it can be passed around.

What if it updates two local vars? Are these translated into 2 objects? Or 1 object with 2 fields. I guess the first one, which is simpler to implement, but I would be more confident having the 2nd approach, essentially an optimization, implemented.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now (2.9), indeed, two separate “holder” objects are used by the Scala compiler to capture the two vars in your closure.

Comment: Thanks for checking. (Wow, after waiting for 2.8 so long, hearing that 2.9 is the current one seems almost a lie! Time flies...). PS: I hope Martin is reading :-)